# Class Module does not exist

Tags: module, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii-components

I'm using [ut8ia/yii2-content-module](https://github.com/ut8ia/yii2-content-module) for content managing. but I have bellow error when I want to use it:

`Class \ut8ia\contentmodule\ContentModule does not exist`

I done as the documentation order.

here is my **config** in `backend`:

```
 'modules' => [
    'content' => [
        'class' => '\ut8ia\contentmodule\ContentModule'
    ],
]
```

In the `vendor\ut8ia\yii2-content-module` **directory**, there is the following class `ContentModule`:

```
namespace ut8ia\contentmodule;

use \yii\base\Module;
use ut8ia\contentmodule\models\Content;

class ContentModule extends Module
{
...
}
```

where is the problem?

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: How did you installed this package?

Comment: @rob006 I use with copmoser. is it not install? or do I have to do something else?

Comment: do you nedd to see my `composer.js`?